# Stacking multiple divs extending width of screen

Tags: html, css

Here's my scenario: I have a few divs that must stack on top of each other. Each div will have a background color (or texture.) Each of the divs has another div nested inside of it. The parent div's color or texture extends the entire width of the screen.

Problem: When adding the second div, it appears above the first.

See what I'm talking about at: http://staging.ontempoideas.com/bvcil

It looks something like this...

HTML:

```
<div id="1P">
<div id="1C">
</div>
</div>
<div id="2P">
<div id="2C">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#1P {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: blue;
}

#1C {
width: 920px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#2P {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: green;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you please add height and width of each div?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not sure exactly what you're after from your description, but I put some code here that may help:  https://jsfiddle.net/JTBennett/hksxgncv/1/

These are the positions you want to be using here:

```
position:relative;
position:inherit;
```

Your two parent divs are set at the same exact absolute position. If you want to clarify anything, I can update it for you.